# How to set exact color to uinavigationbar as given, i need below

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

All i want that the UINavigationBar and the searchView(CustomView)
should have exact same color and without having shadow under the UINavigataionbar. i have tried a lot,i found the soultion for shadow

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage()
```

but still can't able to do same background color on UINavigationBar and searchView. You can see that minor color difference between UINavigationBar and SearchView 
Please don't go for guidelines, if u have answer please share.

Note: SearcView is UIView wid label and an image not UISeachBar.

[image]

Comment: There is no shadows. Because they are different ( colors ). I think you'll need to disable separator color. Right?

Comment: Both are exact same color

Comment: @Mannopson both are color same but i seted "isTranslucent" property is to true. Thanks for the hep you too :)

Answer (score 3):

Try setting `translucent` property of navigationBar to false

**Swift**

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
```

**Objective C**

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTranslucent:NO];
```

**PS: if you want to do it in all the screen, set it globally**

**Swift**

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false
```

**Objective C**

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTranslucent:NO];
```

Comment: Welcome. Pls Accept the answer so that it will help others.

Answer (score 1):

Set your UINavigationBar translucent property false.

Storyboard: In Storyboard uncheck translucent property

[image]

**Swift:**

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
```

**In AppDelegate (didFinishLaunchingWithOptions):**

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the color of navigation bar using this

```
UINavigationBar *bar = [self.navigationController navigationBar];
[bar setTintColor:[UIColor greenColor]]; //Change the color according to your requirement.
```

Comment: can you see that there are some layers on UINavigtaionBar.?

Answer (score 0):

**Try This One**

**Objective C**

```
self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden=NO;
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTitleTextAttributes:     @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:White,NSFontAttributeName:yourFont}];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = yourColor;
```

**Swift**

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = .red //yourColor       
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = .white //yourColor
```